# 3D physics engine / simulator SimSpark on remote machine and forwarding screen via X11

Tags: amazon-ec2, game-engine, x11, nvidia, simulator

I am running a AWS instance (g2.2xlarge with Nvidia GK104GL [GRID K520] GPU) with an Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit) image and ssh'ed into it using the '-Y' flag. Running xeyes or firefox and displaying the remote desktop in a window on my screen works flawlessly.

I am new to running 3D physics engines / games / simulators (remotely). When I want to run the 3D physics simulator SimSpark after successful installing (downloaded from here: https://github.com/BerlinUnited/SimSpark-SPL), I get the following errors:

`libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  23
  Current serial number in output stream:  24`

I tried researching both the libGL errors and the 'X Error of failed request' error without luck. I think there are just too many moving parts for me at the moment.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this? Could this be related with me not having yet installed a Nvidia driver? But does the simulator actually need a GPU in the first place? Appreciate any hints on what to tackle first.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the premature question, solved through some more Googling and these instructions: https://www.scm.com/doc/Installation/Remote_GUI.html